# How to add icon in a button in framework7?

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

I'm a beginner with framework7. I'm trying to insert an icon in a button element.
I'd like to set the icon on the left of the label.
I've achieved my purpose partially.

```
   <a class="button button-fill button-round button-small color-   gray" href="#"  id="add_field_button" style="float: left;"><i class="material-icons ">add_circles</i>Add</a>
```

I've put a demo here.

https://jsfiddle.net/ad72krqv/1/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just adding `icon` to the `<i>` class list provided vertical alignment, so that's a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.button > i {
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link of working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gatmLnhy/)